# Segmentation fault while trying to make a Matrix in C

Tags: c

well, i'm working in C. I want to make a function that return a matrix[][].

This is my function:

```
char **mapa(int largo,int ancho)
{
char **matriz;
int i,j;
matriz = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*largo); 
for(i = 0; i < largo; ++i)
{
    matriz[i]= (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*ancho);
}

for(i = 0; i < largo; i++)
{
        for(j = 0; j < ancho; j++)
    {
        matriz[i][j] = 'k';
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < largo; i++)
{
        for (j = 0; j < ancho; j++)
    {
        printf("%c",matriz[i][j]);
    }
}

return matriz;
}
```

Using gdb it give me this:

```
  Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
  0x00000000004008b8 in mapa (largo=10, ancho=10) at main.c:18
  18                matriz[i][j] = 'k';
```

I don't know where the error is, if someone can give me a hand i'll be very gratefull.
Many thanks.

Comment: should be `matriz = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*largo); `

Comment: This is why you shouldn't repeat the type. Use `largo * sizeof *matriz`.

Comment: There is **no need** to cast `malloc`. It just provides more opportunity for mistake and serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char **matriz;
int i,j;
matriz = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char)*largo);
```

Your `matriz` variable is a pointer to an array of pointers, each of which points to an array of `char`. You first need to allocate memory for the array of pointers, which requires `largo` times the size of the pointers, which is `sizeof (char *)`. You only allocate space for `largo` times the size of a **single** `char`.

The easiest way to get the allocation right is to use the following pattern:

```
p = malloc (n * sizeof *p);
```

In other words, allocate `n` times the size of whatever `p` points to. This will automatically allocate the right amount regardless of the type of `p`, assuming you get the `n` right. If you're declaring the pointer in the same line, it looks a little different:

```
T *p = malloc (n * sizeof *p);  /* For some type T */
```

In this case there is an asterisk before `p` on **both** sides. This difference is something you will have to be aware of, especially when you have more than one level of indirection.

Your first allocation, using this pattern, would look like this:

```
matriz = malloc (largo * sizeof *matriz);
```

and the second:

```
matriz[i] = malloc (ancho * sizeof *matriz[i]);
```

Note, that you never have to cast a void pointer (the return value of `malloc()`), and that the argument to the `sizeof` operator only needs parenthesis when it's a type name. When you get rid of the parenthesis, and place the quantity (`ancho`) before the `sizeof` operator, the result is an expression that is very clean and easy to understand. That is, of course, my personal opinion.

Comment: Since it is generally a good idea to **zero** the elements of the matrix, you can use `calloc` instead of `malloc` to create element storage: `matriz[i] = calloc (ancho, sizeof *matriz[i]);`. Otherwise, you will make your call to `malloc` and a second call to `memset` to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your first malloc casts to a pointer of pointer's but that doesn't mean it is.  If you look at your 2nd malloc you're allocating the same thing. So when you dereference `matriz[i][z]` you're dereferencing a charater, not a pointer.  So I believe, it's been a while since I've done C, your first malloc needs to be `(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*largo)`.

Comment: No, he is dereferencing a `char**` -- the problem is only that he is not allocating enough memory (since `sizeof(char) < sizeof(char*)`) and so he overruns the outer array.  (`malloc()` does not allocate objects of a specific type, it just allocates some bytes of memory.)